# Trouble understanding HTML::Element documentation in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I was looking into `HTML:Element` documentation and came across [attr_get_i](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.02/lib/HTML/Element.pm#attr_get_i) method which according to documentation states that:

> In list context, returns a list consisting of the values of the given
>   attribute for $h and for all its ancestors starting from $h and
>   working its way up.

Now, according to the example given there:

```
<html lang='i-klingon'>
     <head><title>Pati Pata</title></head>
     <body>
       <h1 lang='la'>Stuff</h1>
       <p lang='es-MX' align='center'>
         Foo bar baz <cite>Quux</cite>.
       </p>
       <p>Hooboy.</p>
     </body>
   </html>
```

If `$h` is the `<cite> element`, `$h->attr_get_i("lang")` in list context will return the list `('es-MX', 'i-klingon')`.

Now, according to my unuderstanding the returned list should be `('es-MX', 'la', 'i-klingon')` that is it should also consider `<h1 lang='la'>Stuff</h1>` but according to the documentation it doesn't.

Now, why am I wrong here.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why you are wrong? We cannot tell, it is up to you. `<h1>` in your example is not an ancestor of `<cite>`, therefore it is not considered when searching for attributes via inheritance.

Comment: @choroba : The question is why `'la'` is not returned by `attr_get_i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'lang' attributes here are:

```
+-------------+------------------+
|    lang     |       path       |
+-------------+------------------+
| i-klingon   | /html            |
| la          | /html/body/h1    |
| es-MX       | /html/body/p     |
+-------------+------------------+
```

The `<cite>` node does not have `<h1>` as its parent (path is `/html/body/p/cite`), so `<h1>` is not its ancestor. This is why the method does not return it.

Comment: Thanks. I always have trouble understanding the DOM/Tree structure can you suggest me a nice detailed/descriptive intro for the same.

Answer (score 1):

`<h1 lang='la'>Stuff</h1>` is not an ancestor of  `<cite>`, it is a sibling.